# Privacy of users/organizations data in the application

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, architecture, nestjs

I am currently designing an application with many organizations, and each organization will have many users. My concern is about the data privacy and security of these organizations/users. **It should never happen that organization A would see data of organization B and vice versa.**

I want to use **PostgreSQL** and **Node.js** (**Nest.js**), but the technology does not play a strong role here.

I wanted to have one PostgreSQL database where each organization has its schema, for example, orgA.organizations, orgB.organizations, etc. Unfortunately, I found that it is not a good solution. With many schemas, there can be a performance problem. Then I was thinking about database per organization, but it seems like a huge overhead to handle ~1000 databases.

Now, I am thinking about having a *"flat database structure"* - without any schemas and having just one database. Organizations would be just in one table and the same for users.

The concern with data privacy would be solved primarily on the application level - I would check if user A can access the data of organization A. Still, in the database, these data will *"live together"*.

So, my question is - what is the best way/technique to ensure that user A that belongs to organization A, will never see the data of organization B?

Comment: [Schema-based multitenancy with NestJS, TypeORM and PostgresSQL](https://thomasvds.com/schema-based-multitenancy-with-nest-js-type-orm-and-postgres-sql)

Comment: "With many schemas, there can be a performance problem."  Sure, there is always the possibility of performance problems, no matter what you do. If you reject everything where performance problems are not impossible, you will do nothing.